# When is $A \to A[T]/(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian domain of zero characteristic, $h_1,\ldots,h_n \in A[T]$, $B=A[T]/(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$, and assume that $B$ is also a domain.

I suspect that the following claim is not true; I guess there exists a non-flat extension that satisfies condition (2), though I have not yet found it:

**Claim:** TFAE (1) $A \to B$ is formally smooth. (2) $h_1=\ldots=h_n=0$ or the ideal of $A[T]$ generated by $h_1,h_1',\ldots,h_n,h_n'$ is $A[T]$.

Any hint how to prove or disprove the above claim is welcome.

**Remark:** Please notice that in the special case where $n=1$ the above claim is true, see the first comment in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217581/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h

Comment: According to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217581/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h the answer is no.

Comment: Here is one counterexample.  Let $A$ be $\mathbb{C}[x]$.  Let $h_1(T)$ be $T-1$.  let $h_2(T)$ be $T-x$.  Then the ideal generated by $h_1,h'_1,h_2,h'_2$ does equal the entire ring $A[T]$.  Yet the quotient ring is $A[T]/\langle T-1, T-x \rangle \cong A/\langle x-1 \rangle$.  This is not smooth as an $A$-algebra.

Comment: Very nice counterexample, thanks!